# Copying a subdir from another git repo while keeping history

Tags: git

We want to import a subdirectory from another repository (**not** the entire repository) as a subdirectory in a new repository. The subdirectory did not previously exist in the new repository. The old repository will not be updated anymore; we just want the files and their history from it.

I followed [this guide](https://jrsmith3.github.io/merging-a-subdirectory-from-another-repo-via-git-subtree.html), but it doesn't work quite the way I want: if I view the log, every file has "Add 'lib/Target/WDC65816/' from commit 'af2bb7b1f77e6d97c71ba359a75ea716299af374'" as its sole log entry. The old history is still there, but I have to jump through hoops to read it. TortoiseGit doesn't seem to provide a way to read it, for instance. I want to flatten the history so it's as though this subdirectory has always existed in this repository. How do I do this?

Comment: Do you want to keep commits that did not touch the subdirectory? Do you have existing history in the destination repository and do you want to interleave the subdirectory's history with the existing history? Can you rewrite existing histories (source and destination)?

Comment: I don't want to keep commits that didn't touch the subdir. I have a few commits in the destination repo that I'd prefer to keep, if that's what you're asking, but none are in the new subdirectory. I don't understand the bit about rewriting existing histories.

Comment: I decided what I really wanted was to move the folder into its own repository instead, so I followed this guide here, which worked fine: http://gbayer.com/development/moving-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-preserving-history/